# Did I just give away my credentials by trying to connect to the wrong VPN?

Tags: certificates, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to configure AirVPN on my router. I accidentally put in IPs for `airservers.com` domains instead of `airservers.org`.  Does someone else now have my credentials?  If so, the worst they can do is log in to the VPN as me, right?  The information that might have been sent would inclide static key, certificate authority, client certificate, client key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. OpenVPN is constructed in a way that the client and server will mutually authenticate each other, so the credentials is never sent over the wire.

Also, in addition to this, the validation is failed due to mismatch between the imported CA and the server's certificate. So no authentication happened.

Basically, the server sends you some random data, that you sign with your client key, and send along with your certificate to the server. The certificate itself, without the key, cannot be used to login on the VPN as you, and isn't sensitive.

If the Connection succeeded, it just means that AirVPN both owns airserver.org and airservers.com

Comment: Does this mutual authentication occur between endpoints even if users authenticate using a username/password?